# CSS selectors: General HTML element in ID or Class Selector?

Tags: html, css

I have a div `#divWrapper` that holds a `.innerTable` table with `TD`s and `TR`s.
I would like all `TD`s insdie the #wrapper to have border-collapse: collapse and border: 1px solid black.

I was under the impression

```
#divWrapper td {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

should do the trick, but apparently the td part of the selector will apply globally, hence all TDs that have no other direct selectors will also receive the CSS.

Is there a way to construct a selector like i imagined it above ?

```
<div id="divWrapper ">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>want border</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>borderless</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

EDIT Fiddle with actual problem
https://jsfiddle.net/ancientsion/sLt7m5nd/

Comment: No. Only elements that the selector match will have the rules applied to them. Try providing a [mcve].

Comment: in your css specify css rules as #divwrapper tr td to select proper element. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0nLQ0SHSF5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your markup.You have a space after your id,that is messing up everything

```css
#divWrapper table tr td {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="divWrapper">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>want border</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>borderless</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Your solution to the problem mentioned in the fiddle. If you want to select only those td's within #wrapper ,then it should be

## wrapper table tr td ,but you have given it as #wrapper th,td this selects all th elements within wrapper and all td's in the wrapper and outside

check the following solution

```css
#wrapper table th,#wrapper table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>

        header1

      </th>
      <th>

        header2


      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        One
      </td>
      <td>
        two
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        line2
      </td>
      <td>
        cell 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<table>
  
    <th>
      TH
    </th>
  <tr>
    <td style="color: red;">
      TD
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this makes you understand
for more reference
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: please check the Fiddle in the OP and explain to me why the bottom TH/TD gets a border.

Comment: Hey i did not see this..It is because you have given #wrapper th,td which means select th elements within wrapper element and all td's (outside wrapper element too),if you want it to limit to wrapper element change it to #wrapper th td, this selects all td elements with th which are in wrapper container..hope this helps you

Comment: updated the solution please check and let me know if you have any more qestions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of your css selector working just fine.  One has a border, and one does not.  There were a couple spelling errors I corrected.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #divWrapper td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color:red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divWrapper">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>want border</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>borderless</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```